# Different colors for \url and \href commands?

Tags: hyperref

Can `\url` and `\href` commands' hyperlinks be displayed in two different colors. Actually I'd like to keep the default `\href` color (blue) while displaying the `url` command color in a different color, e.g. in green.

The question is motivated by my need to "see" hyperlinks generated by the `\url` command, with a quick inspection of the pdf file.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pagestyle{empty}

\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}

\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/} %% <--- Hyperlink in green

\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this may helps for you:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=cyan,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}
\pagestyle{empty}

\urlstyle{same}

\DeclareUrlCommand\url{\color{green}}
\begin{document}

\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/} %% <--- Hyperlink in green

\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Hello. If the links are broken to two lines, they aren't right links.

Comment: Please use `PDFLaTeX`, or `XeLaTeX`, or `LuaLaTeX`, etc...